# Swift accessing class variable inside closures

Tags: variables, swift, closures

Why in Objective-C I can set instance variable inside a block:

```
@interface CMVServices : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *times;

@implementation CMVServices
@synthesize times=_times;

and set the _times instance variable inside a block:
(some code )
.
.
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
[_times addObjectsFromArray:objects];
}
```

but I can't in Swift?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
var times :AnyObject[]!

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: AnyObject[]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
 self.times = objects
}
```

The message is:
(AnyObject[]?) times = parent failed to evaluate: variable not available

Comment: We are going to need more complete code. You certainly can modify instance variables from inside closures in Swift. Ideally, it would be best if you could provide us with some code we can throw into a playground and reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Swift syntax for `Array` declarations has changed from `AnyObject[]` to `[AnyObject]`
2. If you're still in the class scope, simply use `times` instead of `self.times`.

This works for me in XCode6-Beta4 in a Playground file:

```
import UIKit

class CMVServices : UIViewController {
    var times : [AnyObject] = []

    func testFunc() {
        func findObjects(objects : [AnyObject]!, error : NSError!) {
            times = objects
            var test_str = "still evaluating in Playground here"
        }
        findObjects(["test", "string"], nil)
    }
}

var test = CMVServices()

test.testFunc()
```

and for full-on test of closures themselves, this also works (again, in XCode6-Beta4):

```
import UIKit

class CMVServices : UIViewController {
    var times: [AnyObject] = []

    func testClosure() {
        { (objects : [AnyObject]!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            self.times = objects
            NSLog("still evaluating")
        }(["new", "test", "string"], nil)
    }
}

var test = CMVServices()

test.testClosure()
test.times // ["new", "test", "string"]
```

Comment: Thanks snickle, you hit the target!!