# How to access a class's variable inside a closure?

Tags: ios, swift, function, closures

I readed this topic: [Swift accessing class variable inside closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914670/swift-accessing-class-variable-inside-closures). But not helps to me.

**Problem**

I've a `ViewControllerData` to show data and other `ViewControllerEdit` to edit data. I want send object from `ViewControllerData` to `ViewControllerEdit`, I'm make this with `performSegue` but I can't get the edited object from `ViewControllerEdit`. I want pass it closure (funcReturnFromEdit) like parameter in `prepare` function.

```
class ViewControllerData: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewData: UITableView!
    var saleOrder : SaleOrder?  // THIS! <--------

    // In this closure I want take the edited object.
    let funcReturnFromEdit = { (saleEdited : SaleOrder) -> () in
        self.saleOrder = saleEdited // I can't do this. Error: Value of type '(ViewControllerData) -> () -> (ViewControllerData)' has no member 'saleOrder'
    }

    ....

      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        segue.identifier == "segueEditOrder" {
        let editVc = segue.destination as! ViewControllerEdit
        if saleOrder != nil {
            editVc.saleOrderToEdit = saleOrder!.copy() as! SaleOrder
        }
        editVc.funcReturn = self.funcReturnFromEdit // <-- Not works
    }
}
```

The error is: `Instance member 'saleOrder' cannot be used on type 'ViewControllerData '`

Besided that, I don't know how to create this function on `ViewControllerEdit`

```
class ViewControllerEdit: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var saleOrderToEdit : SaleOrder?

    var funcReturn = { (SaleOrder) -> Void in {} } // <- This not compile. How to do this?

    ...
    /*
     Funcs to make edition...
    */

    func endEditions() {
        funcReturn(saleOrderToEdit) // <- Here I want send to back ViewControllerData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use global variable/method in closure put `self.` before your variable/method

So you can replace this

```
saleOrder = saleEdited
```

with

```
self.saleOrder = saleEdited
```

but it looks that problem is also somewhere else. You just need to pass saleOrder from first to second ViewController where you edit it and then pass data back to first view controller

So, first delete unneccessary code from ViewControllerData:

```
let funcReturnFromEdit = { (saleEdited : SaleOrder) -> () in
    saleOrder = saleEdited // I can't do this. 
}
```

and to fix completion handler in `ViewControllerEdit` replace

```
var funcReturn = { (SaleOrder) -> Void in {} }
```

with

```
var funcReturn : ((SaleOrder) -> ())?
```

also edit your endEditions method because funcReturn is optional

```
func endEditions() {
    funcReturn?(saleOrderToEdit)
}
```

Now just in your ViewControllerData fix `prepare` method to set what should be done when user call `funcReturn` from `ViewControllerEdit`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueEditOrder" {
        let editVc = segue.destination as! ViewControllerEdit
        if let saleOrderToPass = saleOrder {
            editVc.saleOrderToEdit = saleOrderToPass
            editVc.funcReturn = { saleEdited in
                self.saleOrder = saleEdited //This code is executed when you call funcReturn?(saleOrderToEdit) from ViewControllerEdit
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: `Value of type '(ViewControllerData) -> () -> (ViewControllerData)' has no member 'saleOrder'`

Comment: I can create a function to make this: `editVc.funcReturn = { saleEdited in
                self.saleOrder = saleEdited //This code is executed when you call funcReturn?(saleOrderToEdit) from ViewControllerEdit
            }` or I need implement every time that I need?

Comment: @Augusto I’m afraid I don’t understand your question

Comment: It's simple, I want know if I can declare it code block in a variable, to use x times like needed. For example: `var mFuncReturn = { saleEdited in self.saleOrder = saleEdited //This code is executed when you call funcReturn?(saleOrderToEdit) from ViewControllerEdit }` and use `editVc.funcReturn = mFuncReturn`

Comment: @Augusto Yes you can, just declare var mFuncReturn: (SaleOrder) -> () = { saleEdited in self.saleOrder = saleEdited } and then use editVc.funcReturn = mFuncReturn

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare a completion closure in `ViewControllerEdit` and call it in `endEditions`

```
class ViewControllerEdit: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var saleOrderToEdit : SaleOrder!

    var editCompletion : ((SaleOrder)->())?

...

    func endEditions() {
        editCompletion?(saleOrderToEdit)
    }
```

---

In `ViewControllerData` `prepare(for` assign the closure

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueEditOrder" {
        let editVc = segue.destination as! ViewControllerEdit
        if let saleOrderToEdit = saleOrder {
            editVc.saleOrderToEdit = saleOrderToEdit
            editVc.editCompletion = { [weak self] saleEdited in 
                self?.saleOrder = saleEdited
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For safety reasons I recommend to implement also `shouldPerformSegue` to suppress the segue if `saleOrder` is `nil`

```
func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return saleOrderToEdit != nil
}
```

Note: Please don't use ugly *objective-c-ish* `copy()` in Swift

Comment: Why note use `copy()` ? I can't pass the same reference of the object. How I do this?

Comment: `copy` is redundant. A value type like `struct`, `Array` and `Dictionary` is copied by default.

Comment: I think not, I made this because the data edited in `ViewControllerEdit` also was edit the same object in `ViewControllerData`, because this I implemented the copy protocol.

Comment: I re-tested now, `Dictionary` pass your reference, I need copy.

Comment: If `SaleOrder` is a class then editing the passed instance is actually intended and it's more efficient than copying the item back and forth. If you really want value type then declare `SaleOrder` as `struct`.

Comment: what is `[weak self] ` ?

Comment: `[weak self]` captures `self` as weak to avoid a retain cycle. A retain cycle prevents the object from being deallocated.